# Bluetooth does not run in window PC

Tags: java

hi i write a java app about bluetooth
when i run in eclipse console it ran ok
but when i run in command line it occur error 
import javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;

```
public class main {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws BluetoothStateException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws BluetoothStateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LocalDevice local=null;
    local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
    System.out.printf("this is some text");
}

}
```

errors occur

```
C:\Users\HUNGSON\workspace\Java_Test\bin>java main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: main.  Program will exit.
```

please help me !!

Comment: What does you directory structure look like? Your problem is even before anything bluetooth.

Comment: Can it be that your Main.class is in a package? Try to call it with java mypackage.Main

Comment: "Try to call it with java mypackage.Main" you can say more clear

Comment: when I try java javabluetooth.main but it ocuur errors "Error: Could not find or load main class javabluetooth.main" please help me !!!

Comment: here is my full project
http://www.mediafire.com/?dbb4pik1q5d0g5b

Comment: you need to specify the classpath. Find your `main.class` and `java -cp . main`